# Crop and Plot a rectangle in a map from rnaturalearth does not work anymore

Tags: r, r-sf

The following code:

```
library(rnaturalearth,rnaturalearthdata)
library("sf")

#load world map and crop the rectangle I want
blank2 <- ne_countries(scale = "large",type = 'countries', returnclass = "sf")
blank1 <- st_crop(blank2 , xmin = -22, xmax = 44, ymin = 30, ymax = 66)

# plot map
plot(st_geometry(blank1),col="gray85",lty=0)
```

was plotting a rectangular map until  a few weeks ago. Now, it plots a kind of cylindrical map:
[map of Europe which is not rectangular any more](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMRRC.png)

It is as if the default projection has changed at some stage, but I do not find where, everything in principle is WGS84.

Has the plot function changed something, or the sf package, or the rnaturalearth package?

I use R 4.0.4 with updated packages on a windows machine.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Hi! It might be related to recent changes in sf package. Can you share the output of `packageVersion("sf")` ?

Comment: packageVersion("sf")  gives:    [1] ‘1.0.1’

Comment: I should add that ggplot2 works well. The code:

Comment: library(ggplot2)

sea <- rgb(240/255,248/255,255/255,.5)
 
ggplot(data = blank2)+theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill =sea))+
    geom_sf(colour = "gray85",fill="gray85")+
    coord_sf(xlim=c(-22,44),ylim=c(30,66))

Comment: gives a rectangular map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes because the sf package has changed its default geometry. Adding the command:     sf_use_s2(FALSE)     allows to get back to its original behavior.

Comment: I think it would help, for completeness, to show where in your flow you used `sf_use_s2(FALSE)`, for us boneheads following along. Thanks.

Comment: sf_use_s2(FALSE)  should come just after loading the sf package

Comment: And accept your answer to complete the virtuous circle.